# When/How to dispose of a Web Browser Control after Show Print Preview Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a new Web Browser control in my windows forms project to print some formatted HTML. The user does not need to see the control since it is simply printing a specially formatted version of the page that they are on.

This is the process of printing I am currently using.

```
    internal void PrintQuestion(SessionPart SessionPart)
    {
        WebBrowser wbForPrinting = new WebBrowser(); //<-- Undisposed local
        wbForPrinting.Parent = this;
        wbForPrinting.DocumentCompleted += wbForPrinting_DocumentCompleted;
        wbForPrinting.DocumentText = string.Format(DOCUMENT_HTML, SessionPart.Session.Course.Product.Name, HtmlFormatter.GetPrintableQuestion(SessionPart));
    }

    void wbForPrinting_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
        ((WebBrowser)sender).ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
    }
```

I can not dispose of the WebBrowser right after the show print preview dialog because that would destroy the object I am attempting to print. There does not seem to be an event or way of determining that the user is done with the WebBrowser (either by finishing the print, or canceling the preview). This is the last piece of this project and my time is running out, I do not want to leave an undisposed local.

Comment: Are you wanting to clear Cache..? or Dispose ..? have you looked at Marshalling..?

Comment: I am attempting to Dispose of the WebBrowser. No I have not looked at Marshalling, not sure what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this

```
void wbForPrinting_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
    // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
}
```

[Printing with Web Browser Control and Disposing afterwards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3.aspx)

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I tried, and as mentioned in the question "I can not dispose of the WebBrowser right after the the show print preview dialog because that would destroy the object I am attempting to print.

Comment: Have you tried the example in the link that I have posted in the answer..? Click on the Printing with Web Browser Control and Disposing afterwards.. also when the document to be printed loads.. when you step thru the code what's happening..? also wrap your code around a Try{}Catch{} easier to figure out..if you have an exception

Comment: Well for what ever reason, likely a I-D-10-T error, this method was not working prior to my posting the question. Now however it works as intended.

Comment: Awesome.. glad that I could lend a hand.